# Writing to file in S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, stream

I want to create a file in my S3 bucket.

I have a list which has some 10,000 strings in single iteration, I want to write those to a S3, clear the list. Then, in the second iteration, list is populated again with 10,000 entries, is it possible to write these new 10,000 entries to the same file in my S3 bucket ? How can I store these entries in S3 without storing it on local machine ?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your use-case? How will the list be used? There might be a better method to pass this information to the consuming service.

Comment: The list is of strings with each string having10-15 characters. The list is to be written to S3 bucket on every iteration. I do not want to create a file and store it on local machine since the file can be large enough to cause out of memory. I want the list to be directly dumped to s3 at every iteration.

Comment: What will be consuming (using) the list? It's possible that using a queue would be better, but it depends on what you'll be doing with the list.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to store objects in Amazon S3.

The simplest is to **copy a local file to S3**, which can be done programmatically or with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). For example:

```
aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://my-bucket/foo.txt
```

The `aws s3 cp` command also has the ability to take input from `stdin` and send output to `stdout`. So, if you have a program outputting text to `stdout`, you could store it in S3 with:

```
./myapp | aws s3 cp - s3://my-bucket/foo.txt
```

See: *Uploading a local file stream to S3* in [AWS S3 CP documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html).

Alternatively, you could **write objects to Amazon S3 directly from your application** by using an [AWS SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/#sdk) for your preferred language. This could, for example, stream the data into an Amazon S3 object without having to write it to a local disk first.

Comment: Is it necessory to create a local file?

Comment: You can avoid a local file by using my second example (streaming from stdin) or by incorporating the AWS SDK into your app and calling Amazon S3 directly.